# VHDL DMUX with Generics (1:8 DMUX)

Tags: generics, vhdl

I wrote this entity but i don't know how to write the architecture.It has to be done by using generics and it needs to work for any DMUX (1:2,1:4,1:8,1:16 etc) if I change the Nr_sel (number of selection inputs). The data(input) is on 1 bit.

```
entity DMUX is
generic (
    Nr_sel: integer:= 3
);
port (
    Input: in std_logic;
    Sel: in std_logic_vector (Nr_sel - 1 downto 0);
    Outputs: out std_logic_vector(2**Nr_sel - 1 downto 0)
);  
end DMUX;
```

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more context or code snippet?

Comment: Try the search function before asking.  This appears to have been asked before. See  [Use a generic to determine (de)mux size in VHDL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891700/use-a-generic-to-determine-demux-size-in-vhdl)

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved the following way:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity DMUX is
    Generic (
        num_sel : positive := 1 -- or 2, 3, ... etc.
    );
    Port (
        SEL  : in   unsigned(num_sel - 1 downto 0);
        DIN  : in   std_logic;
        DOUT : out  std_logic_vector(2**num_sel - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity DMUX;

architecture Behavioral of DMUX is
begin

output_p : process (
    SEL,
    DIN
    )
begin

    -- default assignment
    DOUT <= (others => '0');
    DOUT(to_integer(SEL)) <= DIN;

end process output_p;

end architecture Behavioral;
```

Depending on your needs, you could also have low-active logic, i.e. all ones (others => '1') and invert DIN.

Comment: This isn't valid VHDL. See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 11.3 Process Statement, the BNF, re: your line 29 the reserved work `process` is required, as in `end process output_p;` where `output_p` is the process label.

Comment: Aren't there two drivers for the same signal?

Comment: @DavidKoontz I typed this in notepad... Why didn't you go ahead and edit it when you noticed?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, there is one driver for DOUT. You get one driver per prices according to the longest prefix rule.

Comment: But `DOUT(to_integer(SEL))` is assigned with 0 and with `DIN`, isn't it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. But it's a sequential statement inside a process, so demultiplexing logic to resolve this will be generated. Prices was supposed to be process above.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In a process, only the last assignment to a signal is effective (until end process or wait statement), so FRob's logic is correct and only a single driver per bit is generated. Note that this is not the case for variables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right method would be to use `generate`, since we have a variable number of outputs, while all of them have to be assigned, and without any sequential logic:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity DMUX is
generic (
    Nr_sel: integer:= 3
);
port (
    Input: in std_logic;
    Sel: in std_logic_vector (Nr_sel - 1 downto 0);
    Outputs: out std_logic_vector(2**Nr_sel - 1 downto 0)
);  
end DMUX;

architecture Arch of DMUX is
begin
    GEN_OUT:
    for i in 0 to (2**Nr_sel - 1) generate
        Outputs(i) <= Input when (to_integer(Sel) = i) else '0';
    end generate GEN_OUT;
end Arch;
```

I haven't tested it's functionality, but it compiles and gives the idea.